# Data does not save on database after implementing validation

Tags: validation, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I have problem with my validation where after I implement it saveProduct() function, the data that I want to store does not add or update to the database. Also, I shared the product service file, because someone said also have to pass the 'this.productForm.value' inside service file. but I'm not quite sure how.

Below is the code: details.page.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  productName: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
  ])),
  productDecs: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
  ])),
});
}

async saveProduct() {
await this.presentLoading();

this.product.userId = this.authService.getAuth().currentUser.uid;

if (this.productId) {
  try {
    console.log('product update');
    console.log(this.productForm.value);
    await this.productService.updateProduct(this.productId, this.productForm.value);
    await this.loading.dismiss();

    this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/vendor-tabs/home-vendor');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('product dont update');
    this.presentToast('Error trying to save');
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
} else {
  this.product.createdAt = new Date().getTime();

  try {
    console.log(this.productForm.value);
    console.log('product add');
    await this.productService.addProduct(this.productForm.value);
    await this.loading.dismiss();

    this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/vendor-tabs/home-vendor');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('product dont add');
    this.presentToast('Error trying to save');
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
}
}
```

Below is the code for product.service.ts

```
addProduct(product: Product) {
return this.productsCollection.add(product);
}

getProduct(id: string) {
return this.productsCollection.doc<Product>(id).valueChanges();
}

updateProduct(id: string, product: Product) {
return this.productsCollection.doc<Product>(id).update(product);
}

deleteProduct(id: string) {
return this.productsCollection.doc(id).delete();
}
```

Comment: So as per your code, I can't see any observable handled or error in your code can you tell me above code sending data to firebase or you are getting any error at console side Can you please share ?

Comment: Im not getting error on console.

Comment: ok and what about handle observables bcus while calling firebase `add()` function it will return` observer()` and I can't see you handled that in your code?

Comment: I think I don't handle that. Is that necessary to handle?

Comment: not actually but so always its throwing error in the catch or its running without any error?

Comment: its running without errors

Comment: Need help please.

Comment: Check one thing run it on the browser and inspect it and check the network tab in inspect and check what firebase API return while you call add() function.

Comment: already go to network tab and inspect but I don't which to read

Comment: I solved the problem by input [(ngModel)] in html

Comment: greate to hear that u solve your problem!